# Speed up the autoTextView android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a autotextview which get data from a webservice. I have implemented TextChangedListener to it. to get data from internet. Each time on Textchanged new characters are get and on afterTextChanged AsyncTask is called.I want to make it fast because if user enter a text manually .. it take a long time to fetch some new data.

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

            seq = cs;

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
        {
            new SearchTask().execute(seq.toString().trim());
        }
    });
```

AsyncTask is..

```
private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<CharSequence, Void, String> 
{

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    String[] array;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(CharSequence... params) 
    {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(pak_url + params[0]);

            HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

            String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            Log.d("response is", response);

            if (response != null) {
                String substr = response.split("\\(")[2].split("\\)")[0];

                array = substr.split(",");

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

                    array[i] = array[i].replace("'", "");
                }

            }

            return response;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (array != null) {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(PlayListActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

            textView.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.getFilter().filter(seq);
        } 
        /*else {
            Toast.makeText(PlayListActivity.this,
                    "Could not connect to server try again later...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to speedup suggestions or want to stop multiple web requests (in case user types faster than the time it takes to get a server response)?

Comment: i want to speedup suggestion? and i can't stop  multiple web request because each time on afterTextchanged I have to get new list..

Comment: I recommend debouncing the execution of the `SearchTask`. If the user types 5 characters quickly, you're making 4 useless requests because you'll only want the results from the last call. Debouncing would prevent the execution of the task until the user stops typing for a certain interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop multiple requests by following this solution:

```
private SearchTask mAsync;

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
{
    if(mAsync!=null) {
        mAsync.cancel(true);
    }
    mAsync = new SearchTask().execute(seq.toString().trim());
}
```

Now you won't have multiple requests messing up your app.

Also check the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) of `cancel()`. Excerpt reads:

> Calling this method will result in `onCancelled(Object)` being invoked on the UI thread after `doInBackground(Object[])` returns. Calling this method guarantees that `onPostExecute(Object)` is never invoked. After invoking this method, you should check the value returned by `isCancelled()` periodically from `doInBackground(Object[])` to finish the task as early as possible.

Comment: @Nepster it won't speedup the query, there's a delay mainly due to network (sending and receiving) and there's no option but to live with it. As for multiple server calls/API requests, my solution fixes that.